# jQuery bootbox dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get the following code to work

```
//===== Dialogs =====//
$(".table a.delete").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {
            var $el = $(this);
            var $tr = $el.closest('tr');
            var url = $el.closest('table').data('remove-url');
            var id = $tr.data('id');

            $tr.fadeOut(function () {
                $el.remove();
                $.post(url, { id: id }); // do the delete on the server 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The bootbox is showing, but the code below `if(confirmed)` doesnt run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this) inside the anonymous bootbox-method does not refer to what you think it does. The code inside if (confirmed) is executed but does not match anything.

```
$(".table a.delete").click(function (e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {
            var $tr = $el.closest('tr');
            ... etc
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You got me beaten by 5 seconds :)